# How to add lines to a Surface

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

The lines won't show up on the screen for some reason.

Here's what I've tried

```
class Grid(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = pygame.Surface(size)
        self.grid.set_colorkey((0,0,0))

    def draw(self):
        # DRAW TILE LINES ----------------------------------------------------------
        grid_x = 0
        grid_y = 0
        for i in range(GRID_SIZE):
            pygame.draw.aaline(self.grid,BLACK,[grid_x,UPPER_BOUNDARY],[grid_x,LOWER_BOUNDARY],1)
            pygame.draw.aaline(self.grid,BLACK,[LEFT_BOUNDARY,y],[RIGHT_BOUNDARY,grid_y],1)
            grid_x += TILE_SIZE
            grid_y += TILE_SIZE
        # tile test
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,(49*TILE_SIZE,34*TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE))
        screen.blit(self.grid,(0,0))
```

Creating the object:

```
grid = Grid()
```

Calling class: (in main program loop)

```
grid.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your `draw` function a `screen` instance.  Otherwise your blitting it to nothing.

```
def draw(self, screen):
    #...
```

Also remember to call `pygame.display.update()` in your main loop. If you have any questions just comment below.  Good luck!

Comment: He is blitting the lines onto the Grid surface, and later blitting the Grid onto the screen. This is correct. I think display.update() is the issue

Comment: I figured this out last night. It was just a dumb mistake. The colour key was set to (0,0,0) and the lines were BLACK.

Answer (score 0):

You probably lack a `pygame.display.update()` call in your main loop.

I see you have created an object that is a Grid. Since your grid does not change, you could draw the lines once onto the grid, and then only blit the grid onto the main screen in the main loop.

```
class Grid(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = pygame.Surface(size)
        self.grid.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
        self.createGrid()

    def createGrid(self):
        grid_x = 0
        grid_y = 0
        for i in range(GRID_SIZE):
            pygame.draw.aaline(self.grid,BLACK,[grid_x,UPPER_BOUNDARY],[grid_x,LOWER_BOUNDARY],1)
            pygame.draw.aaline(self.grid,BLACK,[LEFT_BOUNDARY,y],[RIGHT_BOUNDARY,grid_y],1)
            grid_x += TILE_SIZE
            grid_y += TILE_SIZE

    def draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,(49*TILE_SIZE,34*TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE))
        screen.blit(self.grid,(0,0))
```